# Login to facebook directly from iOS app - facebook sdk 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook

I have seen some apps which do the user login to facebook within the app, using a popup window.

I searched a lot, got to know that Facebook.m needs to be changed. But the method that was to be changed was not there. So I am assuming that was for the previous version of the sdk (fb sdk 3.0)

In sdk 3.1, `FBSession.m` seems to be the file that requires changes. I tried making `safariAuth:NO` at some places, but it didn't help.

I tried replacing all the `FBSessionLoginBehavior` enums by `FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView` That didn't help either.

How to do it?

I use `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:` method to login

Okay there were two places where `safariAuth:YES` was there. I changed the value to NO at first, second, both places. The popup comes but it is just a white screen with an activity indicator. No login stuff appears.

Update: 
So I changed safariAuth:NO at the first place, and FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView  only in the method that I was using. It sort of works now.

Login webView appears, I login. Then web view appears for publish permissions when I try to call the reauthorize method.
It logs in, but not the callback for the method `reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions` and the call back for `startWithGraphPath` are not happening.

Comment: The mechanism that these and other apps use is called OAuth . . you can use an OAuth library, or an SDK built on top of that. . .

Comment: But i don't want to spend that much time in this process. Can't just modifying the sdk produce the desired changes?